# How to do a "conditional comparison" in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using a snippet I found that will let me get the row number of a data row. I want to have a stored procedure that will let me get either the odd or even rows of my table depending upon what I pass to the procedure. Here's one of the variations I've tried, but it doesn't "compile":

```
create procedure SelectByMod
    @ModNum int,
    @Keyword varchar(2) -- 'eq' or 'ne'
as
begin
with temp as (
    select num, row_number() over (order by num) as rownum
    from numbers
)
select rownum, num from temp where
case (@Keyword)
    when 'eq' then rownum % @ModNum = 0
    else rownum % ModNum != 0
end
end
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case is not meant to be used like that, you just need to use `and` / `or`:

```
select rownum, num from temp where
(
  (@Keyword = 'eq' and rownum % @ModNum = 0) or
  (@Keyword != 'eq' and rownum % @ModNum != 0)
)
end
```